# 2005 Camry Key Doesnt unlock door but fob does after DIY actuator replacement

Tags: toyota, camry, key, locks, actuator

I have a 2005 Toyota Camry and my driver door actuator failed. I bought a replacement part, removed the panel and replaced it as I had seen done. The lock works great when using the key fob, interior power locks, or moving the interior lock manually but it does not work when I try to use the key from the exterior.

The camry only has a key entry on the driver side and I worry the fob wont work one day and I will be stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that when you replaced the actuator you missed the linkage that connects the key cylinder to the rest of the system.  Open the door panel up again and look for a dangling (or perhaps missing....look down in the bottom of the door, it could have fallen off completely) piece of linkage.  Then once you find it just re-install it.  Shouldn't be much of a task.